# How to enable native packaging in netbeans 12.4

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

In order to enable native packaging in netbeans [this tutorial](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html) instruct to click the checkbox in front of "Enable Native Packaging Actions in Project Menu" at Right_Click_On_Project > Properties > Under_Build_Group > Click_The_Deployment_Node. See the image below from the tutorial.
[image]

But in my netbeans copy (Netbeans 12.4) there is no group called "Deployment" under "Build" group. See my screenshot below.
[image]
How can I add the "Deployement" group into my Netbeans Build 12.4? How can I compile my maven project "Native Packing in Netbeans"?

Comment: That's probably because you are using a Maven-based project (my guess), and I believe this packaging option was only available for NetBeans Ant-based projects (File > New Project > Java with Ant). Having said that, the last time I was aware of native packaging being supported like this in NetBeans was for Java 7 (or possibly 8) - no idea if it's still supported today. I have never used it.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion!. I also think this is not supporting now.

Comment: For more recent versions of Java, look at Java's support for [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html). See also [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java14-jpackage).